# Skip some tokens depending on boolean value

Tags: java, antlr4

I have a grammar file for ANTLR4.
I have some `'('` and `')'` tokens in it and I would like for ANTLR4 to skip it depending on if a static `boolean` is equal to `true`.

Example:

```
example
   :    '(' IDENTIFIER ')'

IDENTIFIER: [a-z]+;
```

I would like for the `(` and `)` tokens to be skipped if a certain static `boolean` is `true.

`Any way of doing this?

Comment: What does "skip it" mean exactly?

Comment: To have it not be required anymore, as if it wasn't put in the grammar at all.

Comment: In a parser rule? In a lexer rule? It would greatly help with some examples of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @BartKiers added example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
grammar T;

@parser::members {
  boolean skipParens = true;
}

example
 : {skipParens}? IDENTIFIER
 |               '(' IDENTIFIER ')'
 ;

IDENTIFIER
 : [a-z]+
 ;
```

Note that by doing this, your grammar is tied to a specific language (Java, in this case).